# Newbie here,codeblocks showing this message every time i try to build or run

Tags: c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEzt7.png)[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEPkG.png)

Tried installing different versions .But the problem prevails.

Comment: Please don't share images of code or errors. Use plain text.

Comment: You are also lacking a `}` in line `5`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo not only there

Comment: @Jabberwocky Ah, yes, there's a missing `{` at line `2`  :)

Comment: I think this question is not about the pythonesque syntax errors...

Comment: I attached the wrong screenshot.I tried using "{}" this .But the problem is still there. I think there might be a thing wrong with compiler thats why i can't build and run

Answer (score 0):

You must write `int main() { ... }`, i.e. put `{` and `}` around your function code.

Comment: Tried using that.Still showing the error message

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be new to using Code::Blocks.  What I saw from your image was the standard "Hello World" program (and missing the parentheses as noted in the comments).  If you are actually starting out using Code::Blocks, it will actually create a simple C program for you like yours.  When you start up Code::Blocks, you can just select the creation of a new project.

[image: New Project]

Then, you can select a console project.

[image: Console project]

Next, since your example is a C program, you would select C as the program type.

[image: Program type]

You would give your project a name and select the location to save your project.

[image: Project name]

On the next message screen, you can probably just click on the "Finish" button.  You will then have a simple program that looks like yours.

[image: Initial program]

Code::Blocks happens to be the IDE I utilize the most, but there are many good IDE's out there.  If you happen to continue utilizing Code::Blocks, it has a lot of tips available from the "Help" menu selection.

Hope that adds to the comments you have received and clarifies things a bit.

Regards.

Comment: Hello fellow mate.I still am having that problem even after implementing that.My college project is due for it.Is there any other way

Comment: So you are saying that when you went through the steps of creating a new console project, Code::Blocks created a program without the curly braces?